# Play 2.1, BCrypt: hash yml password attribute before yml-parser generates User object and inserts password value

Tags: playframework, yaml, bcrypt

I'm trying to implement login functionality using the play 2.1 framework. At first i just used plaintext storing of passwords (for which all tests succeeded), so now I've written an enhancement using the JBcrypt library.
My code should be correct (also according to the principles used in https://github.com/yesnault/Play20StartApp/tree/master/app). Now however, when i try to run the same login testcases, they fail. BCrypt gives an 'invalid salt version error'. I've been searching why, but i think i found the problem. To have some initial test data before executing the test I load a test-data.yml file with some users defined as:

```
- !!models.Person
    ID: 123
    lastName:  Tom 
    firstName:  Tom
    password:   secret
```

In my Person class constructor, password is hashed using the Bcrypt hashpw() method and then the hashed password is stored in the user object. The problem however now is (at least that's what i think) that the yaml parser (?) doesn't use my constructor but just creates an empty Person object, and manually fills in its values. So the password isn't hashed and has value 'secret'.
So then when i try to test the login functionality and use BCrypt.checkpw(), it compares 'secret' to 'secret' instead of 'secret' to '-bcryptsalt+hashedpassword' and that's why it gives an error 'salt version invalid', because 'secret' has not the required salt form etc.

So my question is:
Is it possible to call a method in a yml-file? 
For example:

```
- !!models.Person
    bebrasID:   123
    lastName:   Tom
    firstName:  Tom
    password:   BCrypt.hashpw('secret', BCrypt.gensalt())
```

Or is there some way I can force yml to use my constructor instead of manually filling the values? 
So actually, i just need a method using my data yml-file to use BCrypt on a plaintext password before yaml stores it in the Person object? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to call functions inside yml since it is just a "human friendly data serialization standard",as it says in www.yaml.org and you can't serialize functions. What I would suggest is for you to put the hashed password in the yml. Just call BCrypt.hashpw('secret', BCrypt.gensalt())  inside a UnitTest and Log the result, then make sure it will always have the same result and just use that text inside the yml.

Comment: I did another workaround, but this will also work :) Thanks! Just hoped there was an easier way.